# What is the probability that everyone in the UK picks the same combination of numbers for the lottery?

Tags: probability, combinations

There are 64,100,000 people in the UK. The national lottery uses 6 distinct numbers chosen from the set 1 to 49.
What is the probability that all 64 million people at random will pick the same combination of numbers from the given set.

Curiousity is putting a hole in my brain!! Please help!! Thanks

Comment: The answer is $$\left( \frac{1}{\binom{49}{6}} \right)^{64099999} < 10^{-400000000}$$ which is quite small.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{49}6 = 13,983,816$ possible *combinations* for such a lottery.

The first person could choose any number,
the remaining $64,099,999$ must get the same number.

Thus $Pr = \left({\dfrac1{13983816}}\right)^{64099999}$

$\approx= 1$ in  $ 1.9\times 10^{458034600}\;$ hardly worth bothering about !

Comment: Really small typo: $C(49,6)$ is 1398381**6**, not 13983818.

Comment: Thanks, the devil removed, the computation was for 13983816, though !

Answer (score 0):

The UK national lottery now uses a set of $n=59$ distinct numbers $[1,59]$. Each entry is a chosen selection of $k=6$ distinct numbers from that set.

The number of possible combinations of $k$ distinct objects chosen from $n$  distinct objects is
$$\binom{n}k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
The two cases are:
$$\binom{49}6=13,983,816$$
$$\binom{59}6=45,057,474$$
Assuming $a$ people make exactly $1$ entry each, and that people's choices are both uniform and independent then the probability of all $p$ choices being the same is
$$P=\frac1{\binom{n}k}^{a-1}=\binom{n}k^{1-a}$$
So for $49$ numbers, $6$ selections, and $64,100,000$ people:
\begin{align}
P&=13,983,816^{-64,999,999}\\
&=10^{-\log_{10}(13,983,816)\times64,999,999}\\
&\approx10^{-458,000,000}\\
\end{align}
Or for $59$ numbers, $6$ selections, and $64,100,000$ people:
\begin{align}
P&=45,057,474^{-64,999,999}\\
&=10^{-\log_{10}(45,057,474)\times64,999,999}\\
&\approx10^{-491,000,000}\\
\end{align}
The assumptions are incorrect, although this fact will not change the extremely improbable nature of such an event.

Firstly, many numbers are picked more often than others by people in the population (for example numbers appearing in dates), so the choices are not chosen exactly uniformly, but it is unlikely that people will collude to try to choose the same numbers or that such an attempt would be successful.

Secondly some people make many entries so will most likely have spread the numbers across their tickets, maybe they have some crossover but they usually choose more than six numbers in total, but it is highly unlikely that everyone will suddenly buy millions of tickets each.

But two questions do arise here - what are the chances of every person holding a ticket with the same selection and what are the chances of everyone having chosen the same six numbers across their set of tickets? It could be interesting to look at these odds in smaller lotteries.

However, regardless of all this mathematics, some UK residents, like me, do not play the lottery at all which immediately yields an answer to the posed problem of:

> $$0$$

---